# Multiple conditions with logical AND operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to implement a logical AND statement such that the field has a character limit greater than 0 and less than or equal to 100.  Where's my try:

```
    document.getElementById('order-content').onkeyup = () => {
        if (document.getElementById('order-content').value.length > 0 && 
            document.getElementById('order-content').value.length <= 100 ) {
            document.getElementById('order-button').disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('order-button').disabled = true;
        }
```

This is not working and the syntax is undoubtedly incorrect.  Can anyone help me with the way to implement this properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not.  I would expect the button to be disabled, but it's still "active" and would permit the user to submit the data.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I'd recommend storing the output of `document.getElementById('order-content')` in a variable rather than fetching it every line-- more typing and not very performant. (Unrelated to the issue; just some advice)

Comment: Pro tip: Whenever you have `if (condition) something = true else something = false` You can write it simply as `something = condition`. If the values are switched, just negate the value to `something = !condition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

The requirements of the length are length > 0 and length <= 100. The expression `(length > 0 && length <= 100 )` will evaluate to true if the length passes the requirements. The exclamation point reverses the boolean.

```
document.getElementById('order-content').onkeyup = () => {
        let length = document.getElementById('order-content').value.length;

    if (!(length > 0 && length <= 100 )){
        document.getElementById('order-button').disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('order-button').disabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: I might argue that, for readabilities sake, it would perhaps make more sense to reverse the commands executed in the `if`/`else` than to reverse the condition with a `!`.  Just my opinion, though.  Also... I'm not sure this is right regardless-- wouldn't this enable the button if the length is greater than 100?